# Making an interface visible across WCF web services

Tags: wcf

I would like to declare an interface in my Web Service layer and then have the caller create objects of this interface type via proxy and use them to call the service methods.
However, when I decorate the interface with DataContract attribute, I get an error saying this attribute can only be applied to class, struct and enum. I don't think that ServiceContract attribute makes sense, as the interface I am trying to expose is used only for data transfer purposes. I also noticed that when the interface was decorated with ServiceContract, it wasn't displayed in the proxy class created.
What is the best practice to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. "DataContract" interface cannot be exposed as part of metadata. Also even if you share the interface (in assembly) your clients will not be able to send their implementation back to your service because receiving side needs real type for deserialized instance.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. What attribute do I need to decorate the Interface so that I can generate a proxy? When there is no attribute and I try proxy generation, I get an error: Service cannot be activated. Could not load type InterfaceType.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want interface exposed as a service (that is the one for proxy generation) it is marked with `ServiceContract` and its methods with `OperationContract`.

Comment: I would like to have an interface defined in my service layer that some of my service objects will implement. However, if I just make a public interface with no attributes and have an object marked with [DataContract] implement it, I get the "Could not load type 'InterfaceType' error when trying to browse the .svc file.

Answer (score 0):

The service contract is used on the interface, that is the name of the services. The data contract is used on the class, the data that you are sending over.

- ServiceContract on the interface
- OperationContract on the methods
- DataContract on Class
- DataMember on properties

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163647.aspx

Comment: I understand the distinction. My question is this: What attribute do I need to decorate an interface to have it visible via the proxy?